# Grab file from Sharepoint using mule esb

Tags: mule, esb

How would I use mule esb to log into sharepoint, grab a file and then save this file to my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by using the Sharepoint connector : https://www.mulesoft.com/library#!/microsoft-sharepoint-integration-connector